# CSS arrange SVGs into offset grid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've been tasked with creating a background like this using SVGs, I'm using React.

I'm wondering if there is an easy CSS way to arrange these in a grid, i.e. with an offset for the second row.

I also need to make the width dynamic, i.e. so there is the right number of icons for the screen width.

I'm pretty sure I know how to do it in javascript, however if anyone knows a simple CSS way that would be really useful.

Currently they are arranged in a simple row

```
.bg-icons{
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: visible;

    svg{
        font-size: 4em;
        margin: 20px;
        opacity: 0.05;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try using nth child to affect every second child and seeing as your using absolute positioning just adjust the top value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something with flexbox by drawing a bunch of columns and offsetting all the odd or even children to the beginning, center, or end of each column.

```css
.bg-icons{
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

svg {
  align-self: end;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  margin: 1px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
svg:nth-child(odd) {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-icons">
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="pink" />
  </svg>
</div>
```